# How to write setter for class member variable?

Tags: c++, setter

I'm trying to write a simple class in c++ with getter and setter for a class member variable. The getter works fine, but I cant write the setter. Is it possible to overwrite the "m_var" with a setter or is this only for pointer-variables possible?

```
class Foo: public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:

MyOtherClass& getVar()  {
    return m_var;
}

private:
  MyOtherClass m_var;
};
```

Comment: is this your full code?

Comment: "but i cant write the setter" what do you mean/

Comment: Something like this: `MyOtherClass setVar(MyOtherClass * var)  {
    m_var = var;
}`

Comment: Hint: Shallow vs Deep-copy? Call-by-value vs Call-by-reference? Copy constructor? That's all that can be said with the code you provided imho.

Comment: My setter looks like this:

void setMyOtherClass(MyOtherClass& var) {
  m_var= var;
}

But i got a error "wihin this context"... i dont know that this mean

Comment: An variable holding the instance of a class is a pointer to a memory region. As a class will does not fit in a memory register. An int however is different, as a int fits in a memory register.

Comment: @DevCoder maybe it means that you attempt to assign a non-assignable instance? Check if you `MyOtherClass` has `operator =`.

Comment: Why do you need a getter and a setter? You can just make m_var public. As you getter and setter are both public. Or do you want to perform some tests or fire some events before assigning a value to m_var? only in that case a setter/getter is useful.

Answer (score 2):

this should be like that :

```
// this is your setter
// you can set the var parameter as const because it is just copied to var
void setVar(const MyOtherClass& var){m_var = var;}

//this is your getter
MyOtherClass& getVar() {return m_var;}

// also this getter should be declared as const because you return a copy 
// of m_var and thus you do not modify the object
MyOtherClass getVarByCopy() const {return m_var;}
```

the following code compiles fine with g++ :

```
class A
{
public :
   int someInt;
};

class B{
    A m_var;
public:
    void setVar(const A& var){m_var = var;}
    A& getVar() {return m_var;}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    B b;
    A a;
    a = b.getVar();
    b.setVar(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why use a const? May the variable of class MyOtherClass never change?

Comment: with this setter i got the following error:

synthesized method 'MyOtherClass& MyOtherClass::operator=(const MyOtherClass&)' first required here

Comment: A const setter should return a const reference !! Write a const and a non const getter.

Comment: @Thomas true, I wrote my answer to quickly and didnt red it once again before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Are we missing something?

```
class Foo: ...
{
.....
.....

MyOtherClass& getVar()  {
return m_var;
}
```

Your

```
getVar()
```

is actually a setter as it returns a non-const reference.

check this code.

```
    class MyOtherClass
    {
    public:
        MyOtherClass(int i=10)
        {
            m_someInt = i;
        }
        int m_someInt;
    };
    class QObject
    {
    };


    class Foo: public QObject 
    {
        // Q_OBJECT
    public:

        MyOtherClass& getVar()  
        {
            return m_var;
        }

    private:
        MyOtherClass m_var;
    };
    void someFunc()
    {
        Foo f1;
        printf("%d", f1.getVar().m_someInt);

        f1.getVar() = 100;
        printf("\r\n %d", f1.getVar().m_someInt);
    }
```

Though i dont like the idea of such design.

If you really want getVar() to only get but not set, then it should be

```
const MyOtherClass& getVar()const  {
return m_var;
}
```